# Powershell script to convert a word table to text

Tags: powershell, vbscript, ms-word

I have this script that is supposed to convert the first table from a word document to text, but unfortunately it does nothing:

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.visible = $false
$folderpath = "C:\mypath\myfile.docx"
$Doc = $word.Documents.open($folderpath)
$Doc.Tables.item(1).ConvertToText
$Doc.saveas([ref]$folderpath, [ref]$SaveFormat::wdFormatDocumentDefault)
$Doc.close()
$word.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word)
```

However using a VB script with essentially the same code does do this seemingly easy task perfectly:

```
Dim wrdApp: Set wrdApp = WScript.CreateObject(""Word.Application"")
Dim wrdDoc
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\mypath\myfile.docx")
wrdDoc.Tables(1).ConvertToText
wrdDoc.SaveAS ("C:\mypath\myfile.docx")
wrdDoc.Close SaveChanges=True
wrdApp.Quit
Set wrdApp = Nothing
Set wrdDoc = Nothing
```

Can anyone point me towards the reason the powershell script is simply not converting the table?

Thank you!
Tiaan

Comment: Hi Matt, SaveFormat is a property I also use in other scripts and seems to work as intended... I can also confirm that the datetime stamp does change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following code and it worked for me. Pretty same as yours. You need to add parenthesis at the end of method `convertToText`(not required in vbscript) and simply save the document.

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.visible = $false
$path = "C:\mypath\myfile.docx"
$Doc = $word.documents.open($path)
$Doc.Tables.item(1).convertToText()    # <--- Add parenthesis () at the end
$Doc.save
$Doc.close
$word.quit
```

Comment: That would make sense if `convertToText()` is a method. Else PowerShell might have just been displaying null to screen so no errors would have been seen.

Comment: @Matt Although it is weird, but it works. When I removed that parenthesis, and ran the code, it executed w/o any errors but didn't convert the table to text. Only when I added the parenthesis, it performed the desired operation. Even `save`, `quit` are methods but they worked even if I didn't add parenthesis after them

Comment: Thanks Gurman! Such a small thing... it makes me feel silly about my frustration.